# How can I prevent BleachBit from clearing iBus Pinyin's memory?

Tags: ibus, bleachbit

I use [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) to regularly clean my system. However, whenever, I run BleachBit, it clears the memory of my iBus Pinyin. For example, my pinyin just learned that I put 你 and 好 together as one word, so it will show these two characters first whenever I type "ni-hao". What BleachBit does currently is clearing my iBus Pinyin's memory, so that I need to "re-teach" pinyin that 你 and 好 goes together. Currently, these are the entries I ticked in BleachBit to be cleaned:

APT:

- autoclean
- autoremove
- clean

Bash:

- History

Chromium: (all selected)

Deep scan: (none selected)

Firefox: (all selected)

Google Chrome: (all selected)

Gwenview: (all selected)

KDE: (all selected)

LibreOffice: (all selected)

Skype: (all selected)

System:

- Broken desktop files
- Cache
- Clipboard
- Recent documents list
- Rotated logs
- Temporary files
- Trash

Thumbnails: (all selected)

VLC media player: (all selected)

X11: (all selected)

The entries not mentioned in this list are NOT selected. By the way, the version of BleachBit I'm using is 1.0, but I'm planning to upgrade to 1.1. Also, my OS is Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any help about this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I've really never understand the purpose of this kind of programs, apart from apt whatever temporal or cache files you delete will only restore with the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Teach pinyin
2. Uncheck all except System and X11.
3. Uncheck Rotated Logs.
4. Run a preview
5. Copy all the filenames to the clipboard
6. Paste them into your favorite text editor
7. Do a search for filenames related to pinyin such as *pinyin* and *ibus*
8. When you find the right filename, whitelist it it in the preferences
9. Also file a [bug ticket](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/help) with BleachBit

By the way, the latest version of [BleachBit is version 1.10](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-110), which is much newer than 1.1.